# Getting "Duplicate key value violates unique constraint" with Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on Springboot application. 

**Problem statement:** 
I am using **sequence** to generate id.
When I am hitting the controller for the first time, then there is no exception, and data is successfully saved into the database. 
But when I am hitting the controller second time, then I am getting :

```
**duplicate key violates unique constraint, Detail: 
Key(id)=(100) already exits.** <br/>
```

But id = 100 was already inserted 10 records earlier.

I have below POJO:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_tbl", schema = "user")
public class Student {

@Id
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String className;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getClassName() {
    return className;
}

public void setClassName(String className) {
    this.className = className;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

**Student Repository**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {

@Query(value = "select nextval('user.student_id')", nativeQuery = true)
Integer createId();

}
```

**PersistStudent**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersistStudent {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public void persistStudent(List<Student> students) {

    try {

        IntStream.range(0, students.size()).forEach(index -> {
            if (students.size() == index || index % 100 == 0) {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }

            entityManager.persist(students.get(index));
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:: " + e);
    }
}

}
```

**Controller**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class StudentContoller {

@Autowired
private PersistStudent persistStudent;

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepo;

@GetMapping(value = "/save")
public void saveStudent() {

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Student stu = new Student();
    stu.setClassName("VII");
    stu.setName("John Doe");
    stu.setId(studentRepo.createId());

    students.add(stu);

    persistStudent.persistStudent(students);
}

}
```

Please help.

Comment: If only JPA provided a way to auto-generate IDs based on a sequence. Oh wait... https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-sequence

Comment: Please show the DDL of the table and the DDL of the Table's pk sequence.

Comment: @JBNizet: Actually, there is a logic to assign id, i.e if(id !=null){generate id from sequence}, else don't generate id at all.

Comment: And that's a terrible idea: now every time the sequence generates an ID that was previously chosen without getting it from the sequence, you'll get an exception. That's probably precisely what is happening here, and why you asked this question: you generated an ID without getting it from the sequence. So of course if the sequence generates the same ID, you get an exception.

Comment: But how come sequence will generate already generated id. The sequence will always generate a new id. For example, if the last generated id was 101, then next would be 102. I am unable to see the wrong thing happening here.

Comment: The sequence will do that. But it won't check that the ID it generates is not used as the PK of your table because you entered a row in there with a hard-coded ID that the sequence didn't generate. If you choose to generate the IDs of an entity using a sequence, then generate them **always** using the sequence. And thus use the JPA support for generated IDs.

Comment: No, let me again explain. Let's say a new student comes in, then we are going to generate id from the sequence. But when an existing student comes in, then we are not going to generate new id, we are simply going to insert it into the DB. There is only 1 way to assign **id**, which is by using the sequence. Even the student which already has an id, would have got id generated from this very sequence.

Comment: OK. Then what prevents you from using the JPA support for auto-generated IDs using a sequence?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204287/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the whole overhead of managing entity id by simply annotating the field Student.id with @Generated . With this you can simply leave the id field empty and at insert time an unique id will be assigned to the entity. I would also advise using the methods from JpaRepository for create/read/update/delete operations.

The code would become:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_tbl", schema = "user")
public class Student {

@Id
@Generated
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String className;
```

....

```
@Service
public class PersistStudent {

@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

@Transactional
public void persistStudent(List<Student> students) {
    studentRepository.saveAll(students);
}
}
```

....

```
@RestController
public class StudentContoller {

@Autowired
private PersistStudent persistStudent;

@GetMapping(value = "/save")
public void saveStudent() {

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Student stu = new Student();
    stu.setClassName("VII");
    stu.setName("John Doe");
    students.add(stu);

    persistStudent.persistStudent(students);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply:
I have tried that approach ( studentRepository.saveAll(students);), but it is taking a long time to save bulk data into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Lets hope your sequence is working fine, then you don't need to call `stu.setId(studentRepo.createId());`

Just add following annotations to your id field:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private int id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but:  actually, there is a logic to assign id, i.e if(id !=null){generate id from sequence}, else don't generate id at all

Comment: what is the use case of this logic  ?

Comment: user case is: If a new student is coming, then only we are going to generate the Id, otherwise we will not.

Comment: if a student is not new, then also you will do a insert ?

Comment: yes, we will insert. If the student is old, then it will have an id. So there is no need to generate new id.

Comment: If the student already exists, why do you want to insert it again, even if you insert it again what will be it's primary key value ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204290/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-yogendra123).